# Vue js Multiple Date picker

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker, nuxt.js

I am creating a component that paints multiple date pickers, the amount of data picker can be one or many, for this I send it through "`props`" the amount that I want to paint.

```
<HelloWorld x="6" />
```

for this example I want you to paint 6 date pickers

my idea is create each date picker dynamically, then capture the value of each one of it and save it in the database, currently I am having an error, it does not create the date picker, and it is showing an error in the formatDatePicker function.

I leave here the code in odesandbox.io, what am I doing wrong?

[Codesandbox repro](https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-violet-4xb1pq?file=/src/HelloWorld.vue:1435-1451)

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain everything in detail so you know what's wrong and avoid future confusions.

First off, like the linter said in the Codesandbox editor:

> Expected to return a value in "item_date" computed property. (vue/return-in-computed-property)eslint
>
> Unexpected side effect in "item_date" computed property. (vue/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties)eslint

You're not supposed to do side-effects i.e set values or call methods.

The purpose of computed properties is to transform data e.g

```js
computed: {
  hasValue() {
    return this.value !== ''
  },

  fullName() {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName
  }
}
```

---

Second, you're misusing `<v-menu />`. Usually, you use button to trigger a menu but you are assigning it to a text field.

---

Lastly, the way you access your dynamic values in this context wouldn't cause a re-render.

Doing

```
<Component v-model="array[index]" />
```

wouldn't work because you have to use the array methods like `push` or `pop` that Vue provided internally.

Basically what happens is like you're doing

```
array = []
array[2] = 2
```

Vue wouldn't know a value was added unless you use Array methods like `push` or `Vue.set`.

Vue under the hood extended the Array so it can attach its magic:

```
Array.prototype.push = function(value) {
  // The actual code for adding value to array
  // Vue's will do its re-render magic
}
```

Docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods

If you need to assign value by index i.e `array[index] = value` then you need to use `Vue.set()` so Vue is informed you want changes.

Docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays

---

Instead, what you should do is just manually bind the `value` and listen for the `input` event.

`v-model` is just a shortcut for `:value` + `@input`

Docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

Do it like

```
<template>
  <Component
    :value="array[index]
    @input="createHandlerForIndex(index)"
  />
</template>

<script>
  computed: {
    arrayHandlers() {
      // Create a handler for each value
      return this.array.map((_, index) => {
        return (value) => {
          this.$set(this.array, index, value)
        }
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

Working demo: https://codepen.io/captainskippah/pen/VwxBwEa?editors=1010